# Library installation issues- rlang

Tags: r, installation, tidyverse, rlang

I have a new laptop that was working with R and R studio and then after updating packages I have run into continual issues loading or installing R packages in R studio.

1. I have tried to uninstall R and R studio deleted all folders associated and then re-installed.
2. removing and re-installing rlang however it keeps coming up as not properly installed.
3. Checked my .libPath ()

**My question is how do you make sure you have closed everything so you do not have any .dll file open and then therefore so that the installer can overwrite .dll? will this solve my issue?**

```
Restarting R session...
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/R-4.0.4/library"

> install.packages("rlang")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_0.4.10.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1181510 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\dhiam\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuiHNNP\downloaded_packages
> tools::checkMD5sums("rlang")
[1] TRUE

> library(rlang)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rlang’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rlang', details:
  call: NULL
  error: The rlang package is not properly installed.
The DLL version does not correspond to the package version.
Please update rlang to the latest version.
Updating packages on Windows requires precautions:
  <https://github.com/jennybc/what-they-forgot/issues/62>

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_xx.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_xx.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_xx.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_xx.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.4 tools_4.0.4    gtable_0.3.0   grid_4.0.4
```

Please also note, I do not have admin rights to this computer (as it is work laptop).

Comment: This is very odd. Have you restarted your computer? That's one way to make sure everything is closed. If it was a problem with the DLL in use though I would have expected an error during install rather than load. You didn't copy over any packages from previous R versions, did you?

Comment: Yes originally I did and it was working fine then I updated packages (which I try to do often) and then this is where the issues have started. I then tried to remove library folder and start again from scratch. Also tried to restart before re-installing R. Could this be anything to do with not having admin rights to my computer?

Comment: If it’s a work computer, maybe they have something installed to block loading of DLLs. I’d ask your tech support for help. This is not an error I’ve seen before and I’ve seen a lot.

Comment: Have you tried the previous version of rlang?  Mine has 0.4.9

Comment: If you don't have admin right, you can always install R libraries in your personal home directory, e.g., include `R_LIBS_USER="~/R/win-library/4.0"` in `.Renviron` file in `Documents`

Comment: @MrFlick Yes thank you this seemed to be the problem. The DLL were being blocked from loading.